# Timing of sign-up process and trigger of onAuthStateChanged() in Vue App causing permissions problems

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

In my vue app, I want to sign users up, create a users document, and then populate the state with pertinent information by pulling information from a document in firebase.

I want to do this in order because if the tasks do not run synchronously, then the app tries to pull the state information from firebase before the document is created.

I think the issue is that I use createUserWithEmailAndPassword(), then I plan to create a User document, but when the auth function fires, then onAuthStateChanged() runs which tries to get the user document (before it was created), thus throwing the permissions error.

userAuth.vue - ISSUE HERE IS THAT SIGN-UP TRIGGERS ONAUTHSTATECHANGED, WHICH TRIES TO PULL THE USER DOCUMENT BEFORE THE SETDOC FUNCTION BELOW RUNS. **Is it because the promise in the handleAuth() action is asynchronous?**

```
 await store.signUp(email.value, password.value);
 const docRef = doc(db, "users", store.userId);
 await setDoc(uDocRef, {
          //user data
        })
```

Pinia store general.js containing sign-up flow and handleauth flow

```
async signUp(email, password) {
  try {
    const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, 
    email, password);

    this.user = res.user;
    this.userId = res.user.uid;
 
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    await this.signOut();
    throw new Error("could not complete signup");
  }

},
async handleAuth() {
 
  const auth = getAuth();
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
  
      if (user) {
        await this.setAuthIsReady(true);
        let info = await this.getUserInfo(user.uid);
        await this.setUser({
          //user document data
        });
        
        }

        resolve();
      } else if (!user) {
        await this.clearUserData();
        await this.setAuthIsReady(false);
        resolve();
      }
      
    });
  });
},
```

In the router index.js

```
Router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
 const authStore = useGenStore();

if (authStore.isAuthenticated != true) {
  await authStore.handleAuth();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I’m not on my computer right now, but reading your issue I can think of a few things you can try:

1. You’re awaiting for the store function to signup but this is not a promise so the await doesn’t work. Try to move the setDoc function to inside the signup function just after “constant res = createUser…”. I assume these will always be needed in one go.
2. Also, I’m not sure if “store.userId” works? Shouldn’t it be something like “store.state.user.uid”?
3. Same question for “uDocRef”. The variable just before is “docRef”.

Hope something helps you! Good luck